# Conditional Weighted Average calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 Dataframes as below

`Teacher_Commission_df` as below

```
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| Subject |  Harare | Redcliff |  Norton |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| Science |  0.100  |   0.125  |  0.145  |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| English |  0.125  |   0.150  |  0.170  |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|  Maths  |  0.090  |   0.115  |  0.135  |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|  Music  |  0.100  |   0.125  |  0.145  |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|  Total  |  0.415  |   0.515  |  0.595  |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
```

`Students_df` as below. (Note No students for `Maths` in `Harare` and `Norton`)

```
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| Subject | Harare | Redcliff | Norton |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| Science |   15   |    18    |   20   |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| English |   35   |    33    |   31   |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|  Maths  |        |    25    |        |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|  Music  |   40   |    42    |   45   |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
```

I need to calculate the weighted average commission of each city, with a condition.

First of all I'll give the desired output and explain the methodology.

desired output is s below.

```
+------------+--------+----------+--------+
| Total_Paid | Harare | Redcliff | Norton |
+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|   Science  |  4.62  |   4.37   |  6.30  |
+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|   English  |  13.46 |   9.61   |  11.46 |
+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|    Maths   |  0.00  |   5.58   |  0.00  |
+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|    Music   |  12.31 |   10.19  |  14.18 |
+------------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Calculation methodology

if in any city column `[Harare, Redcliff, Norton]`, if students of any Subject `[Science, English, Maths, Music]` is  zero then that particular `subject`'s `Teacher_Commission` should be removed in the weight.

For example, in `Students_df`: Take city `Harare` column of  `Science` subject. since, `Maths` is `zero` in `Harare`, the `teacher_Commission` will be calculated as follows. `15 * [0.10 / (0.415 - 0.09)] = 4.62` note the `0.09` removal in the denominator of the total. where as in `Radcliff` it is calculated without removal as `18 * [0.125 / 0.515] = 4.37`

I hope my explanation is clear.

This can be easily done in `Microsoft Excel` by using an `IF` condition. But, I'm looking for a scalable pandas solution.

I'm not sure how to start the calculation process. Hence, please give me a kick start to solve this.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 UPDATE
  I've managed to solve this. Refer to my answer below and suggest for any improvements
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you explain how you get 41.5% and 51.5%?

Comment: Total of each columns of `Teacher_Commission_df`. it's actually `percentage`.for ease of explanation I mentioned `%` in the `Calculation methodology`. I've already solved it. refer my own answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution using pandas

This is actually just two lines of code using pandas:

```py
import numpy as np
df_tmp = teacher_commission_df[~students_df.isnull()]
df = (df_tmp.div(df_tmp.apply(np.nansum, axis=0)) * students_df).fillna(0)
```

Outcome <sup>*(With the new **3 digits precision** data.)*</sup>

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
            Harare   Redcliff     Norton
Subject
Science   4.615385   4.368932   6.304348
English  13.461538   9.611650  11.456522
Maths     0.000000   5.582524   0.000000
Music    12.307692  10.194175  14.184783
```

#### Explanation of the code above

<sup>***Note**: This explanation uses the **2 digit precision** data given in the original question.*</sup>

- First, you may use boolean indexing, by using the [DataFrame.isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html)

```py
In [1]: students_df.isnull()
Out[1]:
         Harare  Redcliff  Norton
Subject
Science   False     False   False
English   False     False   False
Maths      True     False    True
Music     False     False   False
```

- Then, you can select the non-null values from the `teacher_commission_df` using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and the not operator (`~`).

```py
In [3]: teacher_commission_df[~students_df.isnull()]
Out[3]:
         Harare  Redcliff  Norton
Subject
Science    0.10      0.13    0.15
English    0.13      0.15    0.17
Maths       NaN      0.12     NaN
Music      0.10      0.13    0.15
```

- Let's save this temporary dataframe into new variable, `df_tmp`:

```py
In [12]: df_tmp = teacher_commission_df[~students_df.isnull()]
```

- Now, we want to divide value in each cell by the sum of the column values. The sum of column values is calculated, ignoring nans, with the help of [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`np.nansum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html):

```py
In [14]: df_tmp.apply(np.nansum, axis=0)
Out[14]:
Harare      0.33
Redcliff    0.53
Norton      0.47
dtype: float64
```

- Then, combine the summing with division, using [`DataFrame.div()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```py
In [15]: df_tmp.div(df_tmp.apply(np.nansum, axis=0))
Out[15]:
           Harare  Redcliff    Norton
Subject
Science  0.303030  0.245283  0.319149
English  0.393939  0.283019  0.361702
Maths         NaN  0.226415       NaN
Music    0.303030  0.245283  0.319149
```

- Then, multiply the dataframes (elementwise multiplication):

```py
In [16]: df_tmp.div(df_tmp.apply(np.nansum, axis=0)) * students_df
Out[16]:
            Harare   Redcliff     Norton
Subject
Science   4.545455   4.415094   6.382979
English  13.787879   9.339623  11.212766
Maths          NaN   5.660377        NaN
Music    12.121212  10.301887  14.361702
```

- Lastly, fill `NaN` values with zeroes with [DataFrame.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```py
In [17]: (df_tmp.div(df_tmp.apply(np.nansum, axis=0)) * students_df).fillna(0)
Out[17]:
            Harare   Redcliff     Norton
Subject
Science   4.545455   4.415094   6.382979
English  13.787879   9.339623  11.212766
Maths     0.000000   5.660377   0.000000
Music    12.121212  10.301887  14.361702
```

Comment: Looks elegant. But, not getting the required answer. see the result required mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ah! Right, in the last answer I had some copy-paste mistake! :) Corrected! Now, the answer is identical to the required result (excl. some roundoff errors since the example data is given only with 2 digit precision).

Comment: Yes. your code is correct. but, I'm wondering why the rounding off, when I've given the data to 3 digits precision?

Comment: The original data was given in 2 digits precision (at the time when I copied the data to create the example). I have now updated the final values with the 3 digits precision input data.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you need is the row/column index of every empty-null value in the dataframe?

You can use numpy.where(). Depending on the data type of your null object you could

1. Load df as np array
2. I,j = np.where(“NaN”)
3. i and j are now indexes you can use to eliminate the weights if the sizes are same or use dataframe.index to find which weight to remove.

Replace NaN with Null or “” depending on your dtype

This is similar to what you’d do in excel using an IF

Personally I would just make a copy dataframe binary  i.e put a 1 wherever there is a non null value in the dataframe and 0 at null location, then just miltiple the two vectors. But thats probably more processing overhead

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion given by `User : aak`. I've managed to solve this purely from `numpy`.

```
# Load data and fill N/A values
Teacher_Commission_df = pd.read_excel('data_Teacher.xlsx',index_col='Subject', skipfooter=1)
Students_df = pd.read_excel('data_Studenst.xlsx',index_col='Subject')
Students_df.fillna(value=0, inplace= True)


# Convert Dataframes to Numpy Arrays
T = Teacher_Commission_df.to_numpy(dtype='float')
S = Students_df.to_numpy(dtype='float')

# Filter index of ZERO values from Students Numpy Array and 
# replace the correponding Values in teachers Numpy Array
T[np.where(S == 0)] = 0

# creat a temporary Sum numpy array for calculation
Total_Teacher = T.sum(axis=0)

#calculate incentives
Calculations = T * (S/Total_Teacher)

incentives = (pd.DataFrame(Calculations, columns=Students_df.columns, index=Students_df.index)
                  .round(decimals=2)
                  .reset_index())
incentives
```